# How to store information about login in mobile application (offline or online)?

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, mobile, appwrite

I made a simple application that allows you to take pictures offline and tag them. As soon as there is an internet connection, these data are sent to the server.
I use a great backend solution - Appwrite. It works very well.

The last thing I wanted to do was user registration and login. The AppWrite SDK provides ready-made methods for creating user sessions, authentication.
However, I have a problem how it should work if my application also works offline.
E.g.

1. I have an internet connection - I log in to the application - a session is being created.
2. The next time you turn on the application, the login screen should not appear anymore. How is the application to know that a session is active and not to display the login screen if I do not have internet access?
3. The same if I log out of the app when I do not have internet, the previous session will not be deleted.

I would be grateful for any advice on how to achieve this. To sum up - Should user login information be written somewhere local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use shared_preferences (offline)
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences
and firestore (online)
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

Answer (score 0):

Storing the token or storing a boolean as userLogged into a localstorage would be the optimal choice for the application to identify user login.
One simple solution for localstorage is using shared Preferences:https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences